# How do I exit a loop in python

Tags: python

Sorry, I am still a beginner in Python and am unsure how to exit a loop. Firstly I am having trouble with the "q to quit" input. I've messed around with it and can't get the program to exit using q or Q.

```
full_name = input ('Enter a customers name (or q to quit): ')
address = input ("Enter the customer's address: ")
location = input("Enter customer's city, state, and zip code: " )
cancel = 'q'
while cancel == 'q' or cancel == 'Q':
  print ()
  thin_M = 'Thin Mints'
  thin_M = int(input('Enter the number of Thin Mints: ')) 
  while thin_M > 10:
    print ('Sorry we are accepting a maximum of 10 boxes per type.')
```

Secondly, once I reach the while portion I find that if the number entered is over 10 my print statement will just continue to loop over and over again. What should I do to make sure the last print statement does not loop? The program should re-prompt and issue the sorry message. I am not sure if the top is also considered a loop but how would I get q or Q to work with to exit this code as well?

Comment: Your condition to continue the loop is inverted. The loop needs to run *unless* the user inputs q or Q.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly you wanna do to in this code?

Comment: change `while cancel == 'q' or cancel == 'Q':` to `while thin_M.lower() != 'q':` and `while thin_M > 10:` to `if thin_M > 10:` and `cancel=`q`` to `thin_M=''`

Comment: You exit a loop with a **break** statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `break` to get out of a loop. Your code also has some other errors, which I've fixedd. Try this:

```
full_name = input ('Enter a customers name (or q to quit): ')
if full_name == 'q':
  exit()
address = input ("Enter the customer's address: ")
location = input("Enter customer's city, state, and zip code: " )

text = ''
while text.lower() != 'q':
  thin_M = int(input('Enter the number of Thin Mints: '))
  if thin_M > 10:
    print ('Sorry we are accepting a maximum of 10 boxes per type.')
  else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you never change `cancel` variable so the condition is always `True` and it then loops forever. I assume you rather wanted to check `full_name` against `q` as per your input prompt.

Also `thin_M = 'Thin Mints'` assignment is pointless as it gets overwritten before any read, so just remove it.

And finally, 2nd `while` should rather be plain `if`.

```py
full_name = input ('Enter a customers name (or q to quit): ')
address = input ("Enter the customer's address: ")
location = input("Enter customer's city, state, and zip code: " )
cancel = full_name.lower() == 'q'
while cancel == False:
  print ()
  thin_M = int(input('Enter the number of Thin Mints: '))
  if thin_M > 10:
    print ('Sorry we are accepting a maximum of 10 boxes per type.')
  else:
    cancel = True
```

Comment: You're missing a colon after the first `while` statement.

Comment: Also, if `thin_M` is greater than 10 it will loop forever.

Comment: yep, answered too quickly. should be better now